# Download all files under a groupId from Maven Repository through command or Java program

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

Our project is using Nexus Repository Manager to store all the jars.
Along with the jar I see that under a group there are other files like pom.xml, .md5, .sha1 file. I am in need of these files at our server startup.
Is there a way that I can download all the files under a particular group programatically using Java/Curl command/mvn dependency command at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Maven also uses local repository for caching. The default location is `Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository`. You can check this setting in file settings.xml under [maven_dir]/conf/. 

To update dependencies, use `-U` option. i.e. `mvn clean install -U`
Do not forget setting nexus repo inside pom.xml file http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes that I know. But my problem is I want to download the files under the group at runtime. so I dont want to build my package when there is any change in the contents of these XMLs in the repo.

Comment: HOw about [Nesux API](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/08/13/using-the-rest-api-in-nexus-2/)? and [mvn dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html). For example: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get 
    -DrepoUrl=url 
    -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version`

Comment: yes thanks for that. Someone suggested me a good approach as well. 
Basically, club all the xmls into a JAR/ZIP file and upload that zip file under my groupId. Then programatically use CURL/WGET to download the zip and unzip the contents of that zip file (using any available utility) at runtime

Comment: @SwapnilJaju Could you share? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate what do you want me to share?
the approach is very simple : 
1. Put all XMLs under a zip file.
2. Use mvn deploy to load this zip file to my Maven Nexus Repo.
3. Then Programatically during runtime, download the zip file using simple weburl call to that ZIP file.
4. Use ZIP4J or any other library to unzip the contents to my required output folder 
5. Pick files from this server when needed during the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it with the simple approach.
Club all the xmls into a JAR/ZIP file and upload that zip file under my groupId to the Maven Repository. 
Then programatically use CURL/WGET to download the zip and unzip the contents of that zip file (using any available utility) at runtime.

1. Put all XMLs under a zip file.
2. Use mvn deploy to load this zip file to my Maven Nexus Repo.
3. Then Programatically during runtime, download the zip file using simple weburl call to that ZIP file.
4. Use ZIP4J or any other library to unzip the contents to my required output folder
5. Pick files from this server when needed during the flow.

Hope its helpful to someone somewhere sometime. :)